Why is my filter 'status' unclickable following shadcn/ui?
so I'm following the tutorial from shadcn/ui using tanstack/table. I've encounter a problem wherein I get to show the filter options but the it's unclickable.

I'm following the whole tutorial task design, and I even clone the actual source code but I still get the same problem.
Datatablet.tsx.
export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = React.useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = React.useState<ColumnFiltersState>(
    []
  );

  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] =
    React.useState<VisibilityState>({});
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = React.useState({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    initialState: {
      pagination: {
          pageSize: 5,
      },
  },

    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
      
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <DataTableToolbar table={table} />
       ../ rest of the code.
    </div>
  );
}

DataTableToolbar.tsx
export function DataTableToolbar<TData>({
  table,
}: DataTableToolbarProps<TData>) {
  const isFiltered = table.getState().columnFilters.length > 0;


  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mx-2">
      <div className="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-2">
 
        {table.getColumn("status") && (
          <DataTableFacetedFilter
            column={table.getColumn("status")}
            title="Status"
            options={statuses}
          />
        )}
       

        {isFiltered && (
          <Button
            variant="ghost"
            onClick={() => table.resetColumnFilters()}
            className="h-8 px-2 lg:px-3"
          >
            Reset
            <Cross2Icon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


DatafacedFilter.tsx


export function DataTableFacetedFilter<TData, TValue>({
  column,
  title,
  options,
}: DataTableFacetedFilterProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const facets = column?.getFacetedUniqueValues()
  const selectedValues = new Set(column?.getFilterValue() as string[])

  return (
    <Popover>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="outline" size="sm" className="h-8 border-dashed">
          <PlusCircledIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
          {title}
          {selectedValues?.size > 0 && (
            <>
              <Separator orientation="vertical" className="mx-2 h-4" />
              <Badge
                variant="secondary"
                className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal lg:hidden"
              >
                {selectedValues.size}
              </Badge>
              <div className="hidden space-x-1 lg:flex">
                {selectedValues.size > 2 ? (
                  <Badge
                    variant="secondary"
                    className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal"
                  >
                    {selectedValues.size} selected
                  </Badge>
                ) : (
                  options
                    .filter((option) => selectedValues.has(option.value))
                    .map((option) => (
                      <Badge
                        variant="secondary"
                        key={option.value}
                        className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal"
                      >
                        {option.label}
                      </Badge>
                    ))
                )}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0" align="start">
        <Command>
          <CommandInput placeholder={title} />
          <CommandList>
            <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
            <CommandGroup>
              {options.map((option) => {
                const isSelected = selectedValues.has(option.value)
                return (
                  <CommandItem
                    key={option.value}
                    onSelect={() => {
                      if (isSelected) {
                        selectedValues.delete(option.value)
                      } else {
                        selectedValues.add(option.value)
                      }
                      const filterValues = Array.from(selectedValues)
                      column?.setFilterValue(
                        filterValues.length ? filterValues : undefined
                      )
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      className={cn(
                        "mr-2 flex h-4 w-4 items-center justify-center rounded-sm border border-primary",
                        isSelected
                          ? "bg-primary text-primary-foreground"
                          : "opacity-50 [&_svg]:invisible"
                      )}
                    >
                      <CheckIcon className={cn("h-4 w-4")} />
                    </div>
                    {option.icon && (
                      <option.icon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 text-muted-foreground" />
                    )}
                    <span>{option.label}</span>
                    {facets?.get(option.value) && (
                      <span className="ml-auto flex h-4 w-4 items-center justify-center font-mono text-xs">
                        {facets.get(option.value)}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </CommandItem>
                )
              })}
            </CommandGroup>
            {selectedValues.size > 0 && (
              <>
                <CommandSeparator />
                <CommandGroup>
                  <CommandItem
                    onSelect={() => column?.setFilterValue(undefined)}
                    className="justify-center text-center"
                  >
                    Clear filters
                  </CommandItem>
                </CommandGroup>
              </>
            )}
          </CommandList>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  )
}

 export const statuses = [
    {
      value: "pending",
      label: "Pending",
    },
    {
      value: "approved",
      label: "Approved",

    },
   
  ]


would be great if you can share this in a stackblitz or something

check your package.json if the "cmdk" library is like "^1.0.0" remove it and install this version "0.2.0", I would like to reference the answer of  @BlackLabrador for the same question 78454976

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
